# The graph label goes off the page

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer

I was experimenting with some complex queries, and I'm having an issue with the graph. Not only is the label falling off the page (it continues for several page lengths past the graph), I cannot see my graph.

[image: Off the page]

Maybe it should be able to be toggled off?

I just want to see which data points belong to which group...